# Does IText support PAdES signature commitment type?

Tags: java, itext, pades

I have a working software, using IText, that signs documents with all the PAdES profiles, but I need to add the Commitment Type field, how do I do it?

It is kinda the same as the signature Reason, but in the PAdES structure.

Comment: How *exactly* does your working software create signatures with iText? iText supports different approaches in its signing API, and depending on the approach your software takes the answer may differ.

Comment: I did a custom signDeatached with an external signature, because the external signature requires an OTP after sending the data to be signed obtained with the method getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(...). I'm using IText 5.5.13.1 on Android and React Native.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you will have to introduce even more custom code: You need to patch the `getAuthenticatedAttributeSet` method, and you can do so by extracting it and its callers `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` and `getEncodedPKCS7` (and whatever they may require additionally) from `PdfPKCS7` into your code base and extend it to also set the commitment type attribute.